# OP_RETURN custom message in testnet transaction

Tags: blockchain, testnet, op-return

I would like to do a bitcoin transaction in testnet by embedding a custom message in the OP_RETURN. do i have to download the bitcoin core client with and the block chain to do that? or can i use a separate way without downloading the whole blockchain? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing in java using the bitcoinj library, they have a mechanism in place to do it without downloading the full block chain. They just download the header lightweight simplified payment verification (SPV) mode. Maybe you can try that.This is the [link](https://bitcoinj.github.io/).

```
    SendRequest req;
    Transaction transaction = null;

   transaction = new Transaction(networkParameters);

   // the following statement will help to create an OP_RETURN with "Test" as the message
   transaction.addOutput(Coin.ZERO, ScriptBuilder.createOpReturnScript("Test".toString().getBytes()));
   req = SendRequest.forTx(transaction);
```

Comment: This library can be used for testnet transactions?

Comment: Yes you can do it for `testnet`,`mainnet` or `regtest` networks